# FBGraphObjectPickerViewController crash

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift

I'm stuck with a crash in swift when trying to load the data on a [`FBGraphObjectPickerViewController`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBGraphObjectPickerViewController/).
I've tried two different approaches:

```
class FBPickerVC: UIViewController, FBGraphObjectPickerDelegate {

    let graphPVC = FBGraphObjectPickerViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var set = NSSet(objects: "albums")

        graphPVC.session = FBSession.activeSession()
        graphPVC.fieldsForRequest = set
        graphPVC.delegate = self
        graphPVC.loadData() //This line is causing the crash

        self.presentViewController(graphPVC, animated: true) { () -> Void in
            println("done")
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
class FBPickerVC: FBGraphObjectPickerViewController, FBGraphObjectPickerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        session = FBSession.activeSession()
        delegate = self

        var set = NSSet(objects: "albums")
        fieldsForRequest = set

        loadData()

        }
    }
}
```

Both crashing in the same way.

This is the crash I'm getting:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FBGraphObjectPickerViewController: Invalid call to -loadDataSkippingRoundTripIfCached:. This method must be implemented by a subclass, which must not call super.'`

I'm honestly a bit clueless here. I don't really understand the error message it's giving me. And Looking at the FBPlacePickerViewController it's should be the same way it's done. I've tried to read the documentation, and the sample projects they've provided. But there is nothing showing how to use the FBGraphObjectPickerViewController unfortunately. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/UI/FBGraphObjectPickerViewController%2BInternal.h.

It's saying that you must define the '-loadDataSkippingRoundTripIfCached:' method in your view controller. It's an abstract method that will be called, but it's up to you to define what this method should do.

Comment: I don't understand. It's saying it's already called it and that the call was invalid? How would I call it anyways? I've tried to type it in in my viewController, but there is no such method?

Comment: You are calling loadData. That method is trying to call you back. It is trying to call your loadDataSkippingRoundTripIfCached method but you haven't implemented it. Using your second example, your view controller inherits from FBGraphObjectPickerViewController. That VC has this method, and it is throwing the exception. It's saying, you cannot call me, you have to provide your own method by this name. It's an override.

Comment: override func loadDataSkippingRoundTripIfCached(skipRoundTripIfCached: NSNumber)

Comment: Cool, that did the trick! Are you well rehearsed in the IOS SDK Mike?

Comment: @Chris - I haven't used the Facebook SDK, I was just going by the error message. Glad it worked out, take care.